# ionic 3 Adjust volume through ionic range

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic3

I am not able to find any solution for Volume control like mute, unmute, increase/decrease through Ionic range. I have tried Cordova plugin but not able to do this please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can try cordova-volume-control https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-volume-control

Comment: Thank you for your reply . can you please explane  more specific how can i add cordova code in ionic 2/3 app. I am new in ionic.

Comment: see document. Which i Already provided